# How to skip the online dialog when replacing an image?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

Powerpoint has the unpleasant "feature" of wasting time with an option to search for online images via bing when I right click an image in order to replace it. I *always* want to use a local image, so how can I get rid of this?

Comment: This feature is the most annoying feature added. We don't have a perfect solution to this feature but I would recommend you to work OFFLINE so that you don't face much problem.

Comment: Go through this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-powerpoint/only-insert-images-from-offline-sources-when-using/ae6dbf97-a876-4f9e-964b-b987fa3fde6d?auth=1 There is no such perfect solution to this query.